# Javascript array used in bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I want to use my javascript array in my bootstrap carousel in order to make a carousel which uses all of the elements within the array with which it decides what picture should be there. It should also write out what would be my ,

and alt of the picture on the carousel items but don't know how to connect the two, any suggestions? The array I have is

```
const data = [
    {
      src: 'italian.jpg',
      title: 'Italian cuisine',
      subtitle: 'Great italian cuisine',
      alt: 'Image of italian cuisine'
    },
    {
      src: 'mexican.jpg',
      title: 'Mexican cuisine',
      subtitle: 'Amazing mexican cuisine',
      alt: 'Image of mexican cuisine'
    },
    {
      src: 'japanese.jpg',
      title: 'Japanese cuisine',
      subtitle: 'Traditional japanese cuisine',
      alt: 'Image of japanese cuisine'
    }
  ];
document.getElementById("carousel-item").innerHTML = data;
```

The carousel is the basic bootstrap one.

```
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="..." alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>...</h5>
          <p>...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>...</h5>
            <p>...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>...</h5>
            <p>...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
```

Comment: I'd start by looping through all your carousel-item divs, `document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item')` and setting the `img` attributes from the corresponding items in your `data` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the carousel using javascript, you'd create/get an array of data (like you have) -> then create the slide/indicator elements in javascript looping through your array -> then write the HTML you created in that loop to the page. When you do write it to the page, you'll want it to go into the carousel structure, which is why we set up the skeleton of the carousel first, then inserted the slides HTML to it. Below, I create an array for slides and indicators and for each picture in your array, I create the HTML and add it to the relevant array. When the arrays are complete, I add them to the page using join(''). Join('') just takes all the array elements and joins them together to make a string, which is what we're writing to the page.

Remove this line `document.getElementById("carousel-item").innerHTML = data;` - you're not writing an array into an HTML element. Rather, you need to loop through your array and create the slides and the indicators with it.

Start off with the basic skeleton - and I added a div for us to place the slides into. Also, I removed `data-ride="carousel"` since we'll actually activate the carousel after our loop, rather than on page load.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" >
  <ol class="carousel-indicators" id='carousel-indicators'>
      <!-- here is where we'll add the indicators -->
  </ol>
  <div class='carousel-inner' id='carousel-items'>
     <!-- here is where we'll add the slides -->
  </div>
  
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
```

Then at the top we'll get the data ready after the page loads:

```
window.onload = (event) => {
   // const data = [ ... ]
   var slides=[], indicators=[], html='', activeClass
   data.forEach(item => {
     // set up the slide
     activeClass = slides.length == 0 ? ' active ' : '' ; // the carousel has to have 1 active slide when it starts or else nothing will show. We set the first one as 'active' based on the length of the array we're making (when it's 0, that means we on the first one)
     html = '<div class="carousel-item ' + activeClass + '">'
     html += '<img src="' + item.src + '" alt="' + item.alt + '">'
     html += '<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">'
     html += '<h5>' + item.title + '</h5>'
     html += '<p>' + item.subtitle + '</p>'
     html += '</div></div>'
     slides.push(html);
    
     // set up the indicator
     activeClass = indicators.length == 0 ? ' class="active" ' : '' ; // see note about the active slide above- same goes for the indicators
     html = '<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="' + indicators.length + '" ' + activeClass + '></li>';
     indicators.push(html);


   })

   // now add it to your carousel and fire it up!

   document.getElementById('carousel-indicators').innerHTML = indicators.join('');
   document.getElementById('carousel-slides').innerHTML = slides.join('');
   $('#carouselExampleIndicators').carousel(); // This line assumes you have jQuery loaded with Bootstrap
   

};
```

Comment: Seems like the right direction because I dont understand it at all! I've done what you've said and recreated my code to simulate this however I honestly do not know what to add to slides now that I've removed all the core parts of it, just slapping this in on its own does not work obviouslly as I'm still missing the elements I'm supposed to add.

Comment: @MateoMatijevićBošnjak I fixed some errors in my HTML and my script, and added some comments. I tested it locally and it works. Play with this and if you run into problems, try and figure out why and feel free to leave a comment here if you get vexed